get constexpr variable from a lambda function is fine , but compile fail (Visual C++) and fine (gcc) when such statement is in a new lambda
This code compiles fine in gcc, but fail in Visual C++.
MCVE = https://wandbox.org/permlink/SqNI85EospSrwm5T
int main() {
    auto func_do1Pass2=[&]() {
        return 8;
    };
    constexpr int g=func_do1Pass2();
    auto sLambda=[&]() {
        constexpr int g2=func_do1Pass2();  //<== error at Visual C++
    };
}


Error C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant


Who is wrong?  Why?  Please give reference.

Here is my more real example.   What is a workaround for the below code in Visual C++ case?


Code:
void testtt() {
    auto func_do1Pass2=[&]<int s>() {
        return 8;
    };
    [&]<int s2>() {
        ///vvv can edit only here
        constexpr int g2=func_do1Pass2.operator()<s2>();
        ///^^^ can edit only here
    }.operator()<2>();
}


Just make func_do1Pass2 constexpr. See demo

func_do1Pass2 isn't constexpr (yet)

@cppBeginner I rolled back your edit because you should not edit a question to invalidate exitsing answer(s). Instead you should post a new question.

@wohlstad :: Agree. I will obey.

Yup, there are no restrictions on asking new questions as long as they're sufficiently different. Like in your new question you can explicit say and highlight that you're using local variables func_do1Pass2 so that new answer don't get invalidated.

Just make func_do1Pass2 constexpr as shown below. The problem is that in your given code func_do1Pass2 isn't constexpr so it can't be used in constexpr context.
void testtt() {
//--vvvvvvvvv-------------------------------->added constexpr here
    constexpr auto func_do1Pass2=[&]<int s>()  {
        return 8;
    };
    [&]<int s2>() {
        
        constexpr int g2=func_do1Pass2.operator()<s2>();
        
    }.operator()<2>();
}

Working demo

It is useful.    Sorry, I wasn't mention that func_do1Pass2 may modify local variable in some s cases.   Thus, it is impossible to make the lambda constexpr.   It is my fault.   I edited my question.  Thanks. +1

Can we just remove constexpr for the line constexpr int g2=func_do1Pass2.operator()<s2>();
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int localVariable=0; //some local variable
    auto func_do1Pass2=[&]<int s>() {
        if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;}
        ///^ may modify some local variables
        return 8;
    };
    [&]<int s2>() {
        ///vvv can edit only here
        int g2=func_do1Pass2.operator()<s2>();
        ///^^^ can edit only here
    }.operator()<2>();
}

working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rqPEr4qee
And，if you remove the compile parameter /permissive-, the following code can compile successfully.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int localVariable=0; //some local variable
    auto func_do1Pass2=[&]<int s>() {
        if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;}
        ///^ may modify some local variables
        return 8;
    };
    [&]<int s2>() {
        ///vvv can edit only here
        const int g2=func_do1Pass2.operator()<s2>();
        ///^^^ can edit only here
    }.operator()<2>();
}

Working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5jTq835x5

I can't, sorry.

After you have edited, sorry, I need constexpr, not just const.
